# Private constructor with Boost.Python

Tags: c++, boost, binding, boost-python

I am trying to bind a C++ class with a private constructor using Boost.Python.

Let assume that I have the following class:

```
class Test
{
    public:
        static Test& GetInstance()
        {
            static Test globalInstance;
            return globalInstance;
        }

        int content(){return 0;}

    private:
        Test(){std::cout << "Object constructed" << std::endl;}
};
```

This class has a private constructor and to get an instance of the class, we must call the `GetInstance()` method.

I tried to bind it, using the following code:

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(test)
{
    class_<Test>("Test", no_init)
        .def("create", &Test::GetInstance)
        .def("content", &Test::content);
}
```

This code does not compile and gives me two errors:

- `/Sources/Boost/boost/python/detail/invoke.hpp:75:12: error: type 'const boost::python::detail::specify_a_return_value_policy_to_wrap_functions_returning<Test &>' does not provide a call operator`
- `/Sources/Boost/boost/python/detail/caller.hpp:102:98: error: no member named 'get_pytype' in 'boost::python::detail::specify_a_return_value_policy_to_wrap_functions_returning<Test &>'`

However, if I create a function, which calls `GetInstance()`, like the following:

```
Test create()
{
    return Test::GetInstance();
}
```

and that I replace `.def("create", &Test::GetInstance)` by `.def("create", create)` in my binding, everything works fine.

Why can't I use the public `GetInstance()` method directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here actually comes from the lack of explicit return policy. If a function/method does not return by value, we must set its return policy to one of:

- `reference_existing_object`
- `copy_non_const_reference`
- `copy_const_reference`
- `manage_new_object`
- `return_by_value`

So, simply binding the `GetInstance()` method like so:

```
.def("create", &Test::GetInstance, return_value_policy<copy_non_const_reference>())
```

solves the issue.

Hope it can help someone, as the error messages from Boost don't help that much here…